# Replace text within a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a very long list of data that i need to insert into a table. I have a pre-formatted list of queries that does it, in which i go through each query and replace 'X' with part of an item number. Is there any way that i can save myself typing or copying the text dozens of times over by just replacing 'X' with the text I need?

My set of queries is much longer than this but looks like

```
    Insert into Inventory_Ingredients 
    Values ('X300', 1001, '30label', 1, '0', 0)

    Insert into Inventory_Ingredients 
    Values ('X300', 1001, '30b', 1, '0', 0)

    Insert into Inventory_Ingredients 
    Values ('X300', 1001, 'Shrink30', 1, '0', .50/100)

    Insert into Inventory_Ingredients 
    Values ('X300', 1001, 'recipeX', 1, '0', 1.00/100)

    Insert into Inventory_Ingredients 
    Values ('X300', 1001, 'wiznic100', 0*30/100, '0', 2.00/100)

    Insert into Inventory_Ingredients 
    Values ('X300', 1001, 'vg', 30-(select sum(inventory_ingredients.quantity) 
    from inventory_ingredients 
    where itemnum='recipeX' 
    group by itemnum)-(0*30/100), '0', 2.00/100)
```

Comment: how about using a variable instead of X ?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason dynamic SQL wouldn't work for what you're doing? Very useful in situations like this. Or if the X is just for values being inserted rather than for changing the query structure, variables would likely do the trick. Even so, I bet one of the two options will do it for you. Here's a good site for dynamic SQL help... https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: None at all, I just am very new and was previously unaware of its existence. so i can just replace all my 'X' with @X and DECLARE @X varchar(50)  SET @X = 'insert_data_here'?

Comment: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 5
`The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fkInventory_Ingredients". The conflict occurred in database "cresql", table "dbo.Inventory".
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: When I take the `'@X300'` out of ticks, i get `Must declare the scalar variable "@X300".
`

Comment: Presumably because it thinks that `@X300` is the variable here. How do specify that only `@X` is the variable when it must be only part of a string? Maybe something with `SUBSTRING`